# Подсветка корпусов при наведении, как?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, вёрстка

Как сделать также как на этом примере? Совсем не знаю как это делается, поэтому напишите хотя бы в какую сторону смотреть; на чистом css можно сделать такое или без js не обойтись?

[пример](http://privilege-spb.ru/choose-apartment?h=choose-apartment/house/v)

Comment: Это [SVG](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG).

Comment: С помощью SVG рисуете формы корпусов и дальше анимация CSS

Comment: У меня там ничего не подсвечивается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это называется [map HTML](http://htmlbook.ru/html/map)

На данный момент , всё сделано для удобства человека и так же созданы генераторы подобного , как к примеру этот : [HTML MAP generator](http://htmlmapgenerator.ru/index.php?option=com_htmlmapgenerator&view=htmlmapgenerator&Itemid=2) и как раз на этом сервисе я и сделал этот пример ! В сниппете сам пример

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-fckeditor-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.MetaData.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgithub.com/kemayo/maphilight/dd84221dec229fa5525760a1c791eb9e08f20dd3/jquery.maphilight.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("img[usemap]").maphilight();
  });
</script>

  <img alt="m-dom-7.jpg" src="http://mychertezhi.ru/images/modules/files/cache/shots/Stroitelstvo/Arxitect-plani/Mnogo-etazh-doma/m-dom-7.jpg" usemap="#myMap" width="450" height="318" />
  <map name="myMap" id="myMap">
        <area shape="poly" coords="146,117,278,112,280,130,144,131" class="{fill:true,fillColor:'00ff00',fillOpacity:0.4,stroke:true,strokeColor:'330066',strokeOpacity:0.8,strokeWidth:1}" />
        <area shape="poly" coords="278,136,144,134,150,152,278,155" class="{fill:true,fillColor:'00ff00',fillOpacity:0.4,stroke:true,strokeColor:'330066',strokeOpacity:0.8,strokeWidth:1}" />
        <area shape="poly" coords="277,162,149,160,147,177,278,179" class="{fill:true,fillColor:'00ff00',fillOpacity:0.4,stroke:true,strokeColor:'330066',strokeOpacity:0.8,strokeWidth:1}" />
        <area shape="poly" coords="278,182,148,181,148,197,275,203,275,197" class="{fill:true,fillColor:'00ff00',fillOpacity:0.4,stroke:true,strokeColor:'330066',strokeOpacity:0.8,strokeWidth:1}" />
        <area shape="rect" coords="276,207,152,209" class="{fill:true,fillColor:'cd3333',fillOpacity:0.4,stroke:true,strokeColor:'003333',strokeOpacity:0.8,strokeWidth:1}" />
        <area shape="poly" coords="278,210,150,208,149,224,272,223" class="{fill:true,fillColor:'00ff00',fillOpacity:0.4,stroke:true,strokeColor:'330066',strokeOpacity:0.8,strokeWidth:1}" />
    </map>
```

Я сделал только несколько областей в многоэтажке !

p:s
По хорошему если то изображение загружается в виде [svg fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Fills_and_Strokes) и уже потом ищутся координаты , для удобства пользования SVG есть отличные редакторы такие как CorelDraw inkScape и т д 
Лично я это делаю на обычном тетрадном листе

Answer (score 0):

На [чистом CSS](https://jsfiddle.net/Qwerty_Wasd/81v76q6e/):

```css
#block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(http://aykinfo.ru/uploads/news/d8cf6069c56a1a5e891143ed966bf893.jpg);
  transition-duration: 1.5s;
}

#block:hover {
  background-image: url(http://aykinfo.ru/uploads/news/949781238d04ef7db1cb9799e6aff2e6.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div id="block"></div>
```